# How to make a table with forecast keys YearMonth based on date range

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I've got a forecast model I'm trying to implement in SQL from this post [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/forecasting-with-sql).  I've run against some months are missing values and I'd like to add a zero in those months.  So I'm trying to create a table that I'll join and insert zero when one side is null.

I'm here asking about the below code, it does exactly what I want - but it's pretty gross right?

Thoughts for improvement?  I also like to qualify that I'm not a SQL Dev, I'm a supply chain manager. . . :D

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Year1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    /*Then it exists*/
    DROP TABLE #Year1;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Year2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    /*Then it exists*/
    DROP TABLE #Year2;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Year3', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    /*Then it exists*/
    DROP TABLE #Year3;

DECLARE
    @MinDate date = DATEADD(YEAR, -5, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)), @MaxDate date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @startnum int = CONCAT(RIGHT(DATEPART(YY, @MinDate), 2), FORMAT(DATEPART(MONTH, @MinDate), '0#'));
DECLARE @endnum int = 12;

WITH cteYear1 AS
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM cteYear1 WHERE num + 1 <= @startnum + 11
)
SELECT * INTO #Year1 FROM cteYear1;

SET @startnum = CONCAT(LEFT(@startnum, 2) + 1, RIGHT(@startnum, 2));

WITH cteYear2 AS
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM cteYear2 WHERE num + 1 <= @startnum + 11
)
SELECT * INTO #Year2 FROM cteYear2;

SET @startnum = CONCAT(LEFT(@startnum, 2) + 1, RIGHT(@startnum, 2));

WITH cteYear3 AS
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM cteYear3 WHERE num + 1 <= @startnum + 11
)
SELECT * INTO #Year3 FROM cteYear3;

SELECT * FROM #Year1
UNION
SELECT * FROM #Year2
UNION
SELECT * FROM #Year3;
--Etc. for year 4 & 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some sleep and fixed it:

```
DECLARE @MinDate date = DATEADD(YEAR, -4, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));
DECLARE @StartYear int = RIGHT(DATEPART(YY, @MinDate), 2);

DECLARE @AllYears table (num int NOT NULL);

DECLARE @YearLoop AS int = 0;
DECLARE @MonthLoop AS int = 0;

WHILE @YearLoop < 6
BEGIN
    WHILE @MonthLoop < 12
    BEGIN
        SET @MonthLoop = @MonthLoop + 1;

        INSERT INTO @AllYears (num)
        SELECT CONCAT(@StartYear + @YearLoop, FORMAT(@MonthLoop, '0#'));
    END;

    SET @YearLoop = @YearLoop + 1;
    SET @MonthLoop = 0;
END;

DELETE FROM @AllYears
WHERE num >= CONCAT(RIGHT(DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()), 2), FORMAT(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), '0#'));

SELECT num FROM @AllYears;
```